# how to set cookies value when keypress in input

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="jquerycookies.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
 var COOKIE_NAME = 'adqs';
 var options = { path: '/', expires: 10 };
 f = $("#update").val();
 function setCookie(){
  $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'testvmxzcmv', options);
 return false;
 }
 </script>
```

> how to set cookies value when keypress in input

```
 <input type="text"id="update"onClick="javascript:setCookie()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVrwx/)

```
$("#target").keypress(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onClick` from the input (and use spaces between attribute pairs):

```
<input type="text" id="update" />
```

Bind `keyup` in your JS on DOM ready:

```
// DOM ready
$(function() {
  $('#update').keyup(function() {
    setCookie();
  });
});
```